# JSON.stringify issue from jQuery 1.4.4 to 1.5.2

Tags: jquery, json

Have some JavaScript that assigns values to an object using `$.data` and then uses `JSON.stringify`. It was working in 1.4.4 (got actual JSON data) but it is broken in 1.5.2+ (empty data).

What am I doing wrong?

```
$document.ready {
    var o;
    o = {};
    $(o).data("to","to@email.com");
    $(o).data("from","from@email.com");
    $(o).data("html","true");
    $('#log').append(JSON.stringify(o));
};

<div id="log" class="line1"></div>
```

Can be reproduced here: http://jsfiddle.net/Km4M4/6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jsfiddle doesn't have the JSON library included. Also, you're invoking jQuery ready the wrong way.

But any reason why you cannot define it like this:

```
o = {
        "to":"to@email.com",
        "from":"from@email.com",
        "html":"true"
    };
```

Updated working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Km4M4/8/

Comment: Posted the wrong fiddle to start with.  Defining it the way you have it works fine. Now I'm just curious why the other way broke between versions.

Comment: There changes the way `data` is handled in latest version (to be compatible with HTML5 `data` attributes). Maybe that's why it broke. I would dig up jQuery API release notes to find the exact details.

Answer (score 0):

$.data is used to store "programmable attributes" in any html tag. These values are not mented to be serializable. Other case is an object (your case) you want to serialize attributes. Try doing @Mrchief or the more js oriented below

```
var o = {
  a: 'some data',
  b: 'more data'
};
o.foo = bar;

$('#div').text( JSON.stringify(o) );
```

See in this approach there's no need to use quotes because JSON.stringify puts there for you ;)